# Cant get the Access token json from my Oauth 2 request

Tags: php, curl, oauth-2.0

I am trying to connect to the API for controlling my heater.

I have this code that connects perfectly to the server, and gives me a response.

```
 <?php

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    // try to get an access token
    $code = $_GET['code'];
    $url = 'https://api.nibeuplink.com/oauth/token';
    $params = array(
        "code" => $code,
        "client_id" => '*censored*',
        "client_secret" => '*censoret*',
        "redirect_uri" => 'https://' . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"],
        "grant_type" => "authorization_code"
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, constant("CURLOPT_" . 'URL'), $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, constant("CURLOPT_" . 'POST'), true);
    curl_setopt($ch, constant("CURLOPT_" . 'POSTFIELDS'), $params);
    $udput = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    if ($info['http_code'] === 200) {
       $resultat= json_decode($udput, true);
     //var_dump($resultat);




    } else {
        return 'An error happened';
    }
 } else {

    $url = "https://api.nibeuplink.com/oauth/authorize";

    $params = array(
        "response_type" => "code",
        "client_id" => '*censored*',
        "redirect_uri" => 'https://' . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"],
        "scope" => "READSYSTEM",
        "state" => "1234nemligja"
    );

    $request_to = $url . '?' . http_build_query($params);

    header("Location: " . $request_to);
}
?>
```

This gives me a response like this:

```
{"access_token":"*censored*","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":1800,"refresh_token":"*censored*","scope":"READSYSTEM"}
```

I want to get the 'access_token' as a PHP string/object, so i try to convert the curl via

```
$resultat= json_decode($udput, true);
print_r($resultat["access_token"]);
```

..But nothing happens, i only get the complete response output.

Any ideas ?

Comment: As you are printing out a value by associative array key, clearly somewhere in your code you have given this value to the this element of the array. I did put your code in a php file and this worked for me. Is there any other code you have omitted? Could you put here, what you get as output of the var_dump() commented out above?

Comment: This IS the complete code, thats why i am confused :) - if i uncomment the var_dump i get a int(1) response. my goal is to get the Access Token

Comment: Maybe this has something to do with headers.. If i add 'content headers' i get an error. Here is the documentation that i am trying to use [link]https://api.nibeuplink.com/docs/v1

Comment: Can't access the documentation. One thing might be, that the $udput is really one level deeper array than you think. Eg {"result":{"access_token":" etc. This means, that you have to repeat the json_decode() on access_token again, to unpack this.

Comment: It shouldn't be according to the API. I find it strange though that if i uncomment every command to output the result, i still get the result. It seems like i get a plain text response although the API states that every result is in Json.